# Camera Overlay view not showing in Landscape mode for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I have launched camera using UIImagePickerViewController & trying to overlay the another view. I have set the Overlay view for Landscape mode But still it is showing in Portrait mode after overlay to camera view.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by rotating overlay view as below, tmpCamera.cameraOverlayView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 117.81); Hope this saves someones time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   first you selected only potrait mode in app settting
then use this function in viewdidLoad
//Orientation View into LandScape Mode
    -(void)orientationToLandscape{
        CGAffineTransform rotateTransform;
        switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) {
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90*M_PI/180.0);
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90*M_PI/180.0);
                break;

            default:
                rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                break;
        }

        rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(rotateTransform, +90.0, +90.0);
        [self.view setTransform:rotateTransform];


    }
```